# Is it possible to get stack frames of a python script from a separate process?

Tags: python

I am using a handy statistical profiling script that calls `sys._current_frames()` to collect data for a flamegraph, but to do so it must run within the process being profiled, which is often not convenient.

So is there a way to somehow access the frames from a separate python process (from another python script)?

I.e. I want to be able to profile already running python scripts while not touching the way they are started, not wrapping them in anything etc.

I know there are external tools capable of doing this (e.g. pyflame), but I need to do it from a python script without using something platform-dependent etc.

Comment: You do need something platform- and interpreter-specific. Or a higher-level tool that does different platform-specific things on different platforms but provides a consistent API on top of them. There is no cross-platform way to get info from another process; ptrace, dtrace, DebugAttach, DebugActiveProcess, Pinject, etc. are all very different, with different capabilities and APIs and different security rules.

Comment: Once you’ve connected, if you have a way to inject code or run arbitrary code in its process space, you can just call the C API, but if all you have is a way to read its memory and maybe pause its threads you need deep knowledge of interpreter internals. So, you can look at what pyflame does, but it may not even make sense for a different implementation, much less be easy to port.